# time_stamp data type prints all zero in mysql database when inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I am working on inserting blogpost in mysql database with php. Along with the data I want to insert the time when the post is submitted. For this I have created a database with following data types:

> postid(INT), title(varchar), Post(longtext), Userid(INT), posted(TIME_STAMP)

the code for insertion is :

```
$db->insert('userpost',array('title'=>$title,
                             'post'=>$content,
                             'userid'=>$userData->id,
                             'posted' => time(),
                            ))
```

But the problem is after insertion the "POSTED" field shows all zeros. Why this problem is happening and how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your database editor
and
set "posted" field default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Change insert query to this

```
$db->insert('userpost',array('title'=>$title,'post'=>$content,'userid'=>$userData->id))
```

Comment: thanks..looks like it works.Can you please tell me what was the reason that i had to omit it from my sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Current TimeStamp to be taken for each new row added in PHPMyAdmin

```
    `posted` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```